# Python automate html tag addition around text

Tags: html, python-3.x

I have a question. I need to add HTML boiler plate and additional data to a html file. 
I have a script that takes in a CSV file, processes it(clean, sort, etc) and use pandas .to_html. Problem is it gives me only table tags and the contnet inside. 
Content is something like this:

```
<table border="0" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>AK ID</th>
      <th>TOODE</th>
      <th>EAN</th>
      <th>KOOD</th>
      <th>ARVE</th>
      <th>TK</th>
      <th>XML</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>369097</td>
      <td>BENQ LED 21.5 GW2280 VA 0.248 FHD 1920x1080p 20M:1 (typ 3000:1) 250cd 178/178 5ms VGA/2xHDMI, TCO 7.0, Tilt, VESA, col: must</td>
      <td>4718755073298</td>
      <td>9H.LH4LB.QBE</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
...
```

I have multiple CSV files and I need to automate it.
What I need is to add html tags around my .to_html conent. Right now Im doing it manually and that takes time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mycss.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Title</h1>
<h3>Secondary title</h3>

    .to_html content

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of `.to_html()` is simply a string. So prepend and append whatever boilerplate you like when writing HTML files. Apparently you already have a function that can suitably parse an input CSV, so do something like this:

```
import glob
import re

for infile in glob.glob('*.csv'):
    outfile = re.sub(r'\.csv$', '.html', infile)
    df = parse_csv(infile)
    with open(outfile, 'w') as fout:
        fout.write(PREAMBLE + df.to_html() + POSTAMBLE)
```

Comment: Thank You J_H for pointing out that .to_html is a string. It really helped to make the jinja part work since It helped me turn my html file content into a variable! Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/) for that, since compared to string concatenation, it's easier to debug later on. Here's how the code could look like:

***EDIT: modified after comment***

```
import os
import jinja2 

# setup loader
templates_path = os.path.join(__file__, "../templates")
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(templates_path))

# get and fill the template
data_as_html = """<table border="0" class="dataframe">...</table>"""  # from pandas
base_tmpl = env.get_template("base.html")
html = base_tmpl.render(data_as_html=data_as_html)

# write to disk
output_filename = os.path.join(__file__, "../out.html")
with open(output_filename, "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(html)
```

With the template ***templates/base.html*** being something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>The output</title>    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>

        {{ data_as_html }}        

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank You for the asnwer Jeronimo, It's not quite what I need. I don't really need to iterate through a data set with jinja since i have a fully functioning html from pandas to_html. I do need the HTML boilerplate around it. Can jinja do that? My script makes a html file from a csv file(sorts it and removes unnessecary columns, rearranges coulmns). Then I need my css file to make my html file pretty for printing(to paper) and easier reading.

Comment: Ok then I missunderstood. As long as you have the html body ready somewhere as a template file, that's no problem. I edited the answer above accordingly. Or do you want that other HTML to be somehow auto-created?

Comment: That worked, still have a lot to do to fit it in my for loop but I got it working in a way! Thank You for that!